# post comment in my friend photo using javascript code

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm developing an app that display my fiend photo and the comment to this photo i'm get the photo of my friend and now i don't know if it's possible to post comment to my fiend photo or not just my question it's possible to do that?

how i can post comment to my friend photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in familiy with c# so I'm not sure how can you done this programmatically, but You'll have to POST request to

https://graph.facebook.com/LONG_PHOTO_ID/comments&access_token=...

with POST argument `message`

```
FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(fbApp.Session.AccessToken);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = "You're so pretty";

app.Api("/PHOTOID/comments", args, HttpMethod.Post);
```

Comment: I want java script code if you have it

Comment: LOL, you was asking for c# code